# Power BI how to realise lookup value based on specific value on a column (give me the value of stock where the id is 1 and region is R1)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have two tables tab1 which contains the stock of products in each region, and table 2 which contains unique ID and  the name of products. I want to realise a lookupvalue based on ID product and the name of region so I can get the table below, on excel I now that's possible using INDEX and MATCH functions but in DAX langage it's different, please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRA6F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Power Bi is delivering this functionality to you without having to do a lot. As you mention, two table with a relation between them. Validate you have this also in your pbi file.

[image]

Next you can take the Matrix Visual. and set values accordingly.
[image]